# django url concatenation. I don't want to concatenate

Tags: django, django-urls

[image]

when I do something in 'profile' page,
the url is concatenated to the next of 'profile'.
but I want to link to just 'signout'. not 'profile/signout'

[image]

this is my urls.py.

[image]

when ever I do something in 'profile'page,
the href link is concatenated to 'profile'url.

[image]
this is href source.
since this href source is header.html,
this page is included another pages.
and in the other pages, it works well.
only in profile page, the href url is concatenated to 'profile/1' url.

how can I fix it?

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a URL *not starting with a slash or a scheme* is a relative URL. `href="foo"` is equivalent to `href="./foo"`, i.e. it refers to the path `foo` relative to the current path. If you want the top-level path, you want `href="/foo"`.

In Django you're supposed to use the [`{% url %}` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url) to generate URLs, you don't hardcode them. Django will take care to generate the correct URL; especially if you move the app around to other environments, the URL may require a prefix or such, so you should never hardcode the URL.